# Curl 56 HTTP/2 stream 7 Error while pushing changes

Tags: git, http, curl, azure-devops, version-control

I'm trying to push my changes to azure devops using git. But there's a error message display.

```
PS D:\test\myProject> git push
Enumerating objects: 114, done.
Counting objects: 100% (114/114), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (74/74), done.
Writing objects: 100% (74/74), 78.78 KiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 74 (delta 59), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 HTTP/2 stream 7 was reset
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
PS D:\test\myProject>
```

I updated the git to latest versions.
git version 2.41.0windows.3

what can I do?

Comment: `curl 56 HTTP/2 stream 7 was reset` usually suggests a network timeout of some kind.

Comment: You may want to check you curl version : https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/55820

Comment: @thush-dananjan, have you resolved your issue? What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to Mikael Sandberg we need to clean the cache where you have the files that are causing the problem:

```
git rm --cached
git commit --amend -CHEAD
git push
```

Ref: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/git-push-fails-with-quot-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up/qaq-p/1715381